# Unity consume key and motion events in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

How do I consume key events in Android. I have exported my game to a "Google Android Project" and I have tried both overriding the dispatchKeyEvent() and onGenericMotionEvent(), like this:

```
    // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
    // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
    @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        Log.d(String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), "Control");
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
            return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    { 
        Log.d(String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), "Control");
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
```

I have also tried to attach KeyListener handlers directly to the UnityPlayer object, like this:

```
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        mUnityPlayer.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                Log.d(String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), "Control");
                Toast.makeText(UnityPlayerNativeActivity.this, String.valueOf(event.getDeviceId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        );
```

But in both cases, the Java code is not triggering. Any ideas why??

Answer (score 0):

So I'm able to get the values of Jostick AXIS by putting the following under the Unity activity in the manifest. This now triggers onGenericMotionEvent(), but not dispatchKeyEvent().

```
 <meta-data
      android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"
      android:value="true" />
```

I'm assuming this is a bug in (or a 'feature of') unity, so will file a bug report with them directly